# What's my name and how did I construct my signature?

Tags: visual, language

I recently changed my signature and have started rolling it out on forms. Here's the new one in a couple of versions so you can see the range of unimportant vs. important characteristics.

What's my name and how did I construct my signature?

[image: signature]

Hint 1

> It's just my first name.

Hint 2

> It's a Western name, but is not written in a Western script.

Hint 3

> I changed my name just for this site. If you go to my network profile you'll see the name... but you can still try to explain the connection!

Comment: As this is my first question on Puzzling SE and I don't spend much time here, I'm open to suggestions for how it could be improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

> <s>Connor, or some variant spelling</s> Luke

The symbol is

> Arabic, note it's written right to left. Handwritten Arabic also sucks to read...

Comment: Name is right; explanation is not. You'll understand the suckiness to read if you decipher the encryption process correctly :)